# What `visit` parameter value is allowed in scipy.optimize.dual_annealing?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I tried using `scipy.optimize.dual_annealing` to minimize a function of 8 parameters. The search space (as defined by my `bounds`) is rather broad but I know the solution to be close to `x0`. So, after reading the documentation found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.dual_annealing.html#scipy.optimize.dual_annealing), I decided to use a smaller value of the `visit`parameter, which defaults to 2.62 and is supposedly in the range (0, 3].

When I used `visit=0.8`, I got a *RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log* and indeed, in the source code I found this:

```
self._factor2 = np.exp((4.0 - self._visiting_param) * np.log(self._visiting_param - 1.0))
```

(l.62 of _dual_annealing.py)
(basically `self._visiting_param` is straighforwardly assigned the value of `visit`)

So I thought maybe the documentation is wrong, and the range for visit is (1,3].

When I used `visit=1.2`, I got a *FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in log*, due this time to

```
x *= np.exp(-(self._visiting_param - 1.0) * np.log(self._factor6 / factor4) / (3.0 - self._visiting_param))
```

(l.121 of _dual_annealing.py)
where `self._factor6` is negative.

Is this a real bug, a mistaken documentation, or is it just me misunderstanding something? What values can I use for the `visit` parameter in order to search close to x0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you are right and the value range of the visiting parameter is not specified correctly. In fact, in the limiting case 1, the algorithm (theoretically) recovers (classical) simulated annealing as explained in this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437196002713). However, the actual implementation as described therein, from which also `scipy`'s implementation is taken, appears to work only for values greater 1.4.

I have created an issue on github for this:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/12384